# D3 pie chart doesnot showing the color

Tags: javascript, d3.js, d3pie.js

My code is like this. Can you say what is the error? My color is not showing properly although the section text is showing. the data set is the death rate of the US over time.

```
function clicked(d,i) {

  var dataset = [d.females, d.males];
  var pcolor = ["green", "pink"];

  var outerRadius = 60;
  var innerRadius = 0;
  var arc = d3.arc()
        .innerRadius(innerRadius)
        .outerRadius(outerRadius);

  var pie = d3.pie();

  //Easy colors accessible via a 10-step ordinal scale
  //var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

  //Set up groups
  var arcs = svg.selectAll("g.arc")
          .data(pie(dataset))
          .enter()
          .append("g")
          .attr("class", "arcs")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + outerRadius + "," + outerRadius + ")");

  //Draw arc paths
  arcs.append("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
      .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
        console.log(d);
         return pcolor(i);

      });

  //Labels
  arcs.append("text")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
      })
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.value;
      });
}
```

Comment: This is very odd-looking Java, I don't think I've seen this syntax before?

Comment: I think there is a syntax error, try replacing 'return pcolor(i)' with 'return pcolor[i]'